# Scheduling generic IJob<> with Quartz .NET and AdoJobStore

Tags: c#, generics, scheduler, quartz.net, jobs

I'm developing simple scheduler using Quartz .NET. I want to Quartz persists all of jobs and triggers in database, so I set AdoJobStore and **with "normal" jobs it works ok.**

Now, I have problem with deserializing from database generic Jobs. I have class:

```
class DefaultJob<TEventType, TArgsType> : IJob{
 public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
 {
         //do sth
 }
}
```

With RamJobStore and DefaultJob<,> everyting is ok - scheduling and running work.

With AdoJobStore and DefaultJob<,> I can schedule, Quartz saves it to database (I can see it via Management Studio), but when it tries to restore it from database, I'm getting:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' occurred in Quartz.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Quartz.JobPersistenceException' occurred in Quartz.dll
```

I debuged JobFactory, method NewJob isn't invoked at all. Something wrong happens before it.

Anybody could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. The question is pretty old. And seems it needs to be updated with new data. Now, Quartz.NET supports generic jobs. That's all. The sample in the question, now works perfectly.

```
class DefaultJob<TEventType, TArgsType> : IJob {
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    { }
}
```

Comment: It's indeed very old question but thanks for the update!;)

Answer (score 2):

I am forwarding here the answer from Marko Lahma on official Quartz mailing list:

> Quartz.NET does not support generic job types and I feel that it 
>   shouldn't as it can be expressed as well easily by having a base class 
>   that has the generic definition and your every job just inherits this 
>   class and thus defines the generic types.